# Create a Google sheet in DigitalOcean Space

Tags: python, digital-ocean, google-sheets-api

Is it possible to create a Google sheet using the API and store it on another cloud provider's storage?  Say a DigitalOcean space?  I can create a Sheet and store it on Google Drive but I need to be able to store a Spreadsheet in a bucket.

Comment: Google Sheets are only storable on Google Drive / Google Team Drives.

Comment: Thanks  - guess I'll have to use a headless Office Libre server